# Swift- can't align list of movies horizontally at the top of my screen

Tags: listview, swiftui, alignment, contentview

I fetched data from an API and stored it in an array to make a project on my swift app, right now im trying to make the main page where i wanna just display the movie on the screen, i was able to display them already, but not quite how i want it to.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUG8u.png) . i want the movies to be just under the big title "Movies" and Im not finding a way to do it

Here's my view code:

```
        var body: some View {
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                HStack(spacing: 10) {
                    ForEach(movies) { movie in
                        NavigationLink(destination: MovieDetailsView(movie: movie)) {
                            if let url = URL(string: "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500\(movie.posterPath)") {
                                AsyncImage(url: url) { image in
                                    image
                                        .resizable()
                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                } placeholder: {
                                    Color.gray
                                }
                                .frame(width: 100, height: 150)
                            } else {
                                Text("No movies available")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
            }
            .onAppear {
                fetchData()
            }
        }
```

this code is inside a struct called MovieListView, and this struct is inside a class called MoviesManager. Im calling this struct MovieListView inside of the ContentView like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            MoviesManager.MovieListView()
                .navigationTitle("Movies")
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it wasn´t much info.

I´ve tried to use Spacer() to force the movies to the top but it did not work, besides that i have not tried much.

Comment: have you dealt with your previous question?

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine yes i already solved the problem that i had in my previous question.

Comment: ok, I see, you don't mind sharing your **secret** api key, fine, thank you, works well for me. Note, it customary to acknowledge the answers, and accept the one that helps you by clicking the tick mark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

To place your content on top of your screen you can set frame on the Scrollview like this:

```
var body: some View {
    ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
        HStack(spacing: 10) {
            ForEach(movies) { movie in
                Text(movie)
                NavigationLink(destination: MovieDetailsView(movie: movie)) {
                    if let url = URL(string: "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500\(movie.posterPath)") {
                        AsyncImage(url: url) { image in
                            image
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        } placeholder: {
                            Color.gray
                        }
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 150)
                    } else {
                        Text("No movies available")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .padding(.top, 20) // set padding as per your requirement
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
    }
}
```